# Android Studio bitmap save not saving properly

Tags: java, android-studio

I am currently making an Adroid Studio app for school, and in the sign up form I have an image upload feature. It was working up until recently until I fixed my validation, and now it always returns an error (unrelated to the validation file) instead of properly saving the image on the device.

The code of the camera launcher:

```
//Inside OnCreate
camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(!CheckPermission(RegisterActivity.this))
            RequestPermission(RegisterActivity.this);
        else {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From Camera");
            cameraUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, cameraUri);
            StartCamera.launch(cameraIntent);
        }
    }
});

//Outside of OnCreate
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> StartCamera = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
        if(result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK){
            try {
                cameraBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), cameraUri);
                photo.setImageBitmap(cameraBitmap);
                photoError.setError(null);
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The code of the gallery launcher:

```
//Inside OnCreate
gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(!CheckPermission(RegisterActivity.this))
            RequestPermission(RegisterActivity.this);
        else
            StartGallery.launch("image/*");
    }
});

//Outside of OnCreate
ActivityResultLauncher<String> StartGallery = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(), new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(Uri result) {
        try{
            if(result!=null) {
                cameraBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), result);
                photo.setImageBitmap(cameraBitmap);
                photoError.setError(null);
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

The code of the bitmap saving function:

```
//Outside of OnCreate
public boolean SaveBitmapInFolder(Bitmap bitmap){
    photoName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd-HHmmss").format(new Date()) + ".jpg";
    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/MyPhoto");
    if(!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();
    File dest = new File(dir, photoName);
    try{
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        return true;
    }catch (Exception e){
        photoError.setError("An unexpected error has occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have tried to rebuild the project in the build tab (It solves some issues occasionally) and clean up the code of the launchers and saving functions. In the case that the `SaveBitmapInFolder` function returns a false value, I have a toast that shows that an error has occurred, and this is always the result, no matter if the picture was uploaded from the gallery or taken by the camera.

[image: image showing the toast that appears after trying to complete the form]

Does anyone know a fix to this issue? There aren't any errors in the project logs, it just immediately goes to the catch and returns false.